# Eloquent - where has pivot users orWhere has none

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to write a function that will get all "buckets" that are assigned to the auth'd `user` and/or buckets that have NO USERS assigned.

Relations and such, work as they should. Unless I'm missing something?

How can I get all buckets user is assigned too - and also include buckets where no users (including the auth user) are assigned.

1. Buckets **user** is assigned to
2. Buckets where **NO** users have been assigned. i.e. pivot table contains no rows for bucket, etc.

My issue very likely stems from the `orWhere` query...

```
$buckets = Team::currentTeam()->buckets()->with('user')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->orWhere('user_id', function() {
        $query->count();
    }, '<', 0);
})->get();
```

Comment: What are you using the $query->count() for?

Comment: lol using it wrong. My "plan" was to try and count the num of users assigned to bucket. If no users (aka count 0), then also include in object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Didn't tested this but I think this should work. You're looking to remove that `orWhere` query and add `orHas('user', '=', 0)`.

```
$buckets = Team::currentTeam()->buckets()->with('user')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->orHas('user', '=', 0)->get();
```

Comment: cha-ching! Thanks...exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution you might consider is using a `left join`.

**Heads-up**: this *might* not be accurate as I don't know your db schema.

```php
Team::currentTeam()
    ->buckets()
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.bucket_id', '=', 'buckets.id')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('users.id', $user_id)
            ->orWhereNull('user.id');
    });
```

Please also check this blog post

> AND-OR-AND + brackets with Eloquent
>   https://laraveldaily.com/and-or-and-brackets-with-eloquent/